# ng-styleでのwidthを変数にする方法

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://kimagureneet.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/19/050000
上記のページを参照にしているのですが、

ng-style="{ width: '400px' }"

この'400px'を変数にする場合はどのように書けば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

コントローラ内の`$scope`にプロパティを登録すれば、`{{プロパティ名}}`で設定することができます。

JavaScript

```
$scope.widthValue = "'400px'";
```

HTML

```
<div ng-style="{width: {{widthValue}}}">
```